# Radio Button selected value; choice of 3 options

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, alert, getelementbyid

Using HTML and JavaScript only, I am trying to get the first name, surname details and then a choice of favourite colour from three radio buttons. I can get the first name and surname to work, but cannot do the radio buttons?

HTML file:

```
<html>

<title>Task 3</title>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="formDetails">
        First Name:<input type="text" id="firstName"><br>
        Last Name:<input type="text" id="lastName"><br>
        <p>Favourite Colour:</p>
        <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Red">Red<br>
        <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Blue">Blue<br>
        <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Green">Green<br>
        <input type="button" onclick="display()" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
```

JavaScript file:

```
function display(){
var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

alert(firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

I have no idea how to implement the radio buttons? I have seen some people using jQuery, but I want to stick to just JavaScript here as I am fairly new.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Js:

```
var colour=document.querySelector('input[name="colour"]:checked').value;
alert(colour);
```

Comment: It's usually best to explain how the code helps the OP so that later readers can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

Add a class to all your input tags named `check_in`.

Use javascript to find all tags with this class

Iterate through each tag to determine which of them is checked. If a tag is checked add it to the variable named `results`.

Finally get First name and Last name from input box and add these values to your variable named `results`

```js
function display() {
  results = {}
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var all_input = document.getElementsByClassName('check_in');
  for (var i = 0; i < all_input.length; ++i) {
    if (all_input[i].checked == true) {
      results['option'] = all_input[i].value;
    }
  }
  results['firstname'] = firstName;
  results['lastname'] = lastName;
  console.log(results);
  alert('firstname:' + results['firstname'] + ' lastname: ' + results['lastname'] + ' option: ' + results['option']);
}
```

```css
margin:50px auto auto;
```

```html
<html>

<title>Task 3</title>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="formDetails">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" id="firstName">
    <br>Last Name:
    <input type="text" id="lastName">
    <br>
    <p>Favourite Colour:</p>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Red" class="check_in">Red
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Blue" class="check_in">Blue
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="Green" class="check_in">Green
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="display()" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: It's usually best to explain how the code helps the OP so that later readers can understand it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan true..I added some info..Tnks